# JProfiler: Why Proxy class not display in the call tree?

Tags: jprofiler

If I define filter with [default compact config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXjFd.png)

I can see the invocation like this in the [call tree-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlTDs.png) (this is a feign client method)

But if I define filter [profiled all my source package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iQy5.png)

I can't see any invocation in the [call tree-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNshq.png)

Actually, I wish it better to see a tree node display a proxy class call hello() like this
[call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jQIa.png)

How could I do? Jprofiler doc say if a profiled record show in first line, all other class is compact, so I think the proxy class auto generated is compact too, why this proxy class did not show in the call tree?

---

Try with Dr. Ingo Kegel's answer, and got [call tree-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYEAS.png). proxy class call feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler, why proxy disappeared？

Answer (score 0):

If you define the call tree filters to `com.example.`, neither  `$Proxy...` nor `ReflectiveFeing$FeingInvocationHandler` are in the profiled classes. This means that calls into such methods will go into the inherent time of the node of the last profiled class (`com.example....helloA` in this case) and not have separate nodes.

With instrumentation, JProfiler does not record complete call stacks for CPU profiling. If you switch to sampling, you can disable all filters and get complete call stacks.

Comment: I try to use **Full Sample** recording type and **disable all filters**. Still only got `ReflectiveFeing$FeingInvocationHandler` node and not saw Proxy node. I've tried everything. And I define `ReflectiveFeing$FeingInvocationHandler` in the profiled classes, but got a unProfiled icon in the tree node. I am confused.

Comment: Additional Remarks, Profiled list: `com.example.servicea.controller.` + `com.sun.proxy.` + `feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler`.     and newest version of JProfiler

Comment: There is indeed special handling for proxy classes, so they are hidden, but for `feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler` I see the regular icon the screen shot.

Comment: yes,  regular icon in the screen shot tree-1, but unProfiled icon in tree-3, is this a bug? and I still hope proxy node show in call tree, It will be a little bit more intuitive and identifiable.It's not a big deal, though, right. thanks.